# Pass Boolean from Activity to not started Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

On startup my app loads a `SignInActivity.java` wherein the user can chose to Login using various social media platforms or chose to skip. This is logged using a "isLoggedIn" boolean value on the `SignInActivity.java`.

Now a specific fragment (say `FragmentB`) in the app (selected from a `Navigation Drawer`) needs to make use of this value and the fragment is only created after selection from the Navigation Drawer so trying to set arguments on the bundle from the `SignInActivity` is useless.

The method I'm currently using is to send the boolean using an `Intent` to the `MainActivity.java` and then set bundle for `FragmentB`.

However, the issue I face in this is that if the user logs out of his account -- or logs in after Skipping login the first time (there is an option to login/logout of the app post startup via a "My Account" option that leads to the SignInActivity) then the bundle is not updated in `FragmentB` and the app behaves incorrectly.

`getArguments()` is called in the `onCreateView` of `FragmentB`, trying to call it in the `onResume()` method leads to app crash stating that fragment is already active.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences instead...

Comment: Yep, that solved it! Thanks